# Videoview in recyclerview starts playing when listitem just get visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

I putted VideoView in RecyclerView but not directly. I use container with header and footer like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Header -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="HEADER"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"/>

    <!-- Content -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_for_infeed"
        android:layout_below="@id/header"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- FrameLayout for VideoView -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/display_io_add"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp">

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="FOOTER"
        android:textSize="120sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/container_for_infeed"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Layout with VideoView]

Video starts playing when this layout appears on screen and stops when scroll to next position. It is not very good for me because I also have footer and header in the same container and they certainly got visible before VideoView. 
Here is example of scroll position when footer just particularly got visible and video starts:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
  videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onPrepared,  videoView.getVisibility() =   "  + videoView.getVisibility());
                        if (!mp.isPlaying() && (videoView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)) {
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

The question is why videoView considered as Visible even it is not on the screen? And why onPrepared called every time footer become visible?

Comment: Visibility is the state of a view in a context of view's layout tree hierarchy. It doesn't tell you whether a view is currently visible/drawn on to the screen.

Comment: OK, but is there a way to check real visibility on the screen?

Comment: I guess you can compare the view's bounds to the screen's bounds. Also account for view's Z-order to be sure it's not covered by some other view.